# GPG Error Missing Signature

Tags: apt, ppa, software-uninstall

When I do the command below:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

At the bottom I get an error saying

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8873E7BF70F1BBEA
```

How do I retrieve this key from the opensuse.org server? If I were to look on their website I won't be able to find the key. There are so many nested directories on the [website](http://download.opensuse.org), and I don't know where to look to find it. I don't even know what application or what update it's even for.

---

**Update**

I have followed the guides in the comments and it doesn't work. I moved my lists file, and created a new one when using apt-get update. I now have 15 PPA files, and 16 security files. After removing some of the other GPG keys, I now have even MORE errors when updating.

Comment: Which packages comes from this repository?

Comment: How can I find out?

Comment: Have you added a lot of PPAs? If so, check out [this blog post](https://sudodblog.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/fixing-gpg-error-no_pubkey/). If you have more than 40 files in the `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory, it'll cause that error.

Comment: I have followed your guide and it doesn't work. I moved my lists file, and created a new one when using apt-get update. I now how 15 ppa files, and 16 security files.  After removing some of the other gpg keys, I now have even MORE errors when updating.

Comment: Revert the changes. Which keys are now missing?

Comment: I think both of you guys are going about this the wrong way. I need to work out which application is using this key. How do I find this? @AB, I just manually added the NEW keys having errors that were missing because I knew what it was for. Bare in mind, I'm still having the same problem as my original post.

Comment: Run this command `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ {system("apt-cache policy  " $2)}' > out`. Post the content of `out` here http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link

Comment: With the output of the command, we check if you need the repository.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13158962/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31235/discussion-between-a-b-and-john-smith).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to import the right key with the following commands:

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:osmc/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-get update
```

---

*Why? That's why:*

The output of `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ {system("apt-cache policy " $2)}'` tells us that the repository has one package installed in your system:

```
osmc-installer:
  Installed: 111
  Candidate: 111
  Version table:
 *** 111 0
        500 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/osmc/xUbuntu_14.04/  Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And [here](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:osmc&package=osmc-installer&hcolor=17394a&fcolor=17394a&acolor=17394a) are the install instructions for OSMC installer and how to import the key.

---

If you don't need the OSMC installer, remove the package

```
sudo apt-get remove osmc-installer
```

find the repository

```
grep -r 'download.opensuse.org' /etc/apt
```

and remove the repository

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/osmc-installer.list*
```